# Moving window method to aggregate data

Tags: r, loops, aggregate

I have the matrix below:

```
 mat<- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,
       2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
       0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
       0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
       0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
       1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,2,1,0,0,0), nrow=16, ncol=6)
 dimnames(mat)<- list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"), 
              c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

I need to aggregate columns using a moving window method.  First, the window size will be 2, such  that the window is comprised of 2 columns. Row sums are taken for this aggregate. The window will shift by one step and again take row sums. For the example data frame provided, the first columns to be aggregated are columns 1&2, the second window will combine column 2&3, then 3&4, then 4&5 and 5&6.

These results (row sums for each aggregate) are put into a matrix. In this matrix rows are conserved and columns now represent the results for each aggregate.

Next, the moving window size will increase to a size of 3. Such that 3 columns of data are combined (summed). Similarly, the window shifts 1 step. For the example data frame provided, the first columns to be aggregated are columns 1-2-3, the second window will combine columns 2-3-4, then 3-4-5, 4-5-6. Results are put into a separate matrix.

The size of the moving window  will continue to increase until the window is the size of all columns. In this example, the largest window combines all 6 plots.

Below are result matrices for window sizes 2 and 3 given the example matrix above `mat`. Columns are named according to the columns that were added.

```
#Window length =2 
mat1<- matrix( c(3,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,
         2,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
         0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
         0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
         1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,1), nrow=16)
dimnames(mat1)<- list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"), 
              c("1_2", "2_3", "3_4", "4_5", "5_6"))

 #Window length 3
 mat8<- matrix( c(3,0,1,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,
         2,1,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
         0,1,1,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
         1,2,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,1), nrow=16)
 dimnames(mat8)<- list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"), 
              c("1_2_3", "2_3_4", "3_4_5", "4_5_6"))
```

In my example I have 6 columns, so there would be 5 result matrices total. In the event I had 600 columns of data, I am thinking a loop is the most efficient way to iterate over a large dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way in base R

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - 1), function(j) do.call(cbind, 
   lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - j), function(i) rowSums(mat[, i:(i + j)]))))


#[[1]]
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#a    3    2    0    0    1
#c    0    0    1    1    1
#f    0    1    1    0    0
#h    0    1    1    0    0
#i    1    2    1    1    1
#j    0    0    1    1    0
#l    1    0    0    0    0
#m    0    0    0    1    1
#p    0    0    0    0    1
#q    0    0    0    1    1
#s    0    0    0    1    2
#t    0    0    0    0    2
#u    0    0    0    0    1
#v    0    0    0    1    1
#x    3    1    0    0    0
#z    0    0    0    1    1

#[[2]]
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#a    3    2    0    1
#c    0    1    1    2
#f    1    1    1    0
#h    1    1    1    0
#i    2    2    2    1
#j    0    1    1    1
#l    1    0    0    0
#m    0    0    1    1
#p    0    0    0    1
#q    0    0    1    1
#s    0    0    1    2
#t    0    0    0    2
#u    0    0    0    1
#v    0    0    1    1
#x    3    1    0    0
#z    0    0    1    1
#....
```

---

As this is a rolling operation, we can also use `rollapply` from `zoo` with a variable window-width

```
lapply(2:ncol(mat), function(j)
    t(zoo::rollapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), j, function(x) rowSums(mat[,x]))))
```

Comment: Thank you. How would this be modified to randomly choose columns to be aggregated in contrast to sliding windows in a sequence?

Comment: It would require some changes in the inner `lapply`. We need to select `j` random columns using `sample`, do `rowSums` and remove those selected `j` columns so that those are not repeated in the next iteration.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the solution such that the column names specify the columns that were combined? For example, if the moving window combines column 1 & 2, the column name would be "1_2". Similarly, if the moving window combines 3 columns like column 2,3 &4, the column name would indicate "2_3_4" .

Comment: I have tried the following, can you please let me know my error: `lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - 1), function(j) do.call(cbind, 
   lapply(sample(ncol(mat) - j), function(i) rowSums(mat[, i:(i - j)]))))`

Comment: I have posted a second question related to this requesting help with a different binning technique, if you are able to help with that as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083701/bin-columns-and-aggregate-data-via-random-sample-with-replacement-for-iterativel