# Bin columns and aggregate data via random sample with replacement for iteratively larger bin sizes

Tags: r, loops, aggregate, lapply

Below is an example matrix:

```
mat<- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,
   2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
   0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
   1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,2,1,0,0,0), nrow=16, ncol=6)
dimnames(mat)<- list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"), 
          c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

I want to group or bin columns and then aggregate data for each group. First, I would like to bin two columns of data. Binned columns must be adjacent to each other (ie. columns 1&2, columns 5&6 NOT columns 4&6). Where the binning starts in the matrix is random. For example, in a matrix of 600 columns the first two columns binned may be columns 545 & 546 and next columns 3&4. I would like to sample without replacement such that a combination is not sampled twice. Aggregation is defined as calculating row sums for the bin `rowSums()`. Aggregated results will be a new column in a result matrix. The number of columns in the result matrix will be limited to the number of bins randomly sampled.

Bin size continues to get increasingly larger. Next, the bin size increases to 3 such that 3 adjacent columns of data are aggregated. Aggregated data will be  put into a different result matrix. This process would continue until the bin is the size of the data frame. All result matrices would be put into a list of matrices.

I have posted a similar question for an alternative binning technique here: [Moving window method to aggregate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58021216/moving-window-method-to-aggregate-data)

I have tried modifying the code so that the binning technique randomly samples n adjacent columns and calculates row sums:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - 1), function(j) do.call(cbind, 
lapply(sample(ncol(mat)-j, replace = FALSE, size = length(x)), function(i) rowSums(mat[, i:(i + j)]))))
```

I need help modifying this line of code to randomly sample without replacement i adjacent columns of  bin size i for n samples and aggregate each sample using row sums. Note that combinations of columns cannot be resampled but columns can be resampled if they are part of new combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an paramaterized approach that samples from possible combinations without replacement and calculates the summary based on the original data, and labels the result columns so you can see where they came from (and have confidence there are not repeats).

```
set.seed(47)
n_cols_in_bin = 2
n_samps = 4

starting_cols = sample(1:(ncol(mat) -  (n_cols_in_bin - 1)), size = n_samps) 
result = sapply(starting_cols, function(x) rowSums(mat[, x:(x + n_cols_in_bin - 1)]))
colnames(result) = paste0("cols", starting_cols, "to", starting_cols + n_cols_in_bin - 1)
result
#   cols5to6 cols2to3 cols3to4 cols4to5
# a        1        2        0        0
# c        1        0        1        1
# f        0        1        1        0
# h        0        1        1        0
# i        1        2        1        1
# j        0        0        1        1
# l        0        0        0        0
# m        1        0        0        1
# p        1        0        0        0
# q        1        0        0        1
# s        2        0        0        1
# t        2        0        0        0
# u        1        0        0        0
# v        1        0        0        1
# x        0        1        0        0
# z        1        0        0        1
```

For convenience, we can put it in a function:

```
foo = function(mat, n_cols_in_bin, n_samps) {
  starting_cols = sample(1:(ncol(mat) -  (n_cols_in_bin - 1)), size = n_samps)
  result = sapply(starting_cols, function(x)
    rowSums(mat[, x:(x + n_cols_in_bin - 1)]))
  colnames(result) = paste0("cols", starting_cols, "to", starting_cols + n_cols_in_bin - 1)
  result
}

foo(mat, n_cols_in_bin = 3, n_samps = 2)
#   cols3to5 cols4to6
# a        0        1
# c        1        2
# f        1        0
# h        1        0
# i        2        1
# j        1        1
# l        0        0
# m        1        1
# p        0        1
# q        1        1
# s        1        2
# t        0        2
# u        0        1
# v        1        1
# x        0        0
# z        1        1
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I particularly appreciate that you included columns names that specify which columns are combined. The problem however with this solution is it does not resolve iterating over a large dataset. In my actual data I have 600 columns. Thus, bin sizes can range from 2-600. In this case, I would want code that iterates through the original matrix for bin sizes from size 2 to n and aggregates x randomly binned samples for those various sizes.  Ideally, for each bin size I would not have to indicate parameters for bin size separately.

Comment: That's a simple extension of my answer. `results = sapply(2:100, foo, mat = mat, n_samps = 5)` to get 5 samples each for bin sizes from 2 to 100. You just need to write a `for` loop (or `sapply` loop, or whatever) around the function.

Comment: You should only need to modify if the sample is impossible at high bin sizes. That is, if you have 600 columns, there is only one possible sample of 600 consecutive columns... so since a stated requirement is that samples can't be repeated, `foo` will give an error if you ask for more independent samples than exist.

Comment: ok, thank you. One more inquiry. The solution you propose in the previous comment outputs a single result matrix where columns represent bin size and rows are added for increasing samples. How can I output a LIST of result matrices- each result matrix unique to  a specific bin size and columns of those matrices represent samples for that in size (preserving the naming convention in your function)? Having a unique matrix for each bin size could allow for differing dimensions aka. fewer number of samples drawn for increasing bin sizes.

Comment: For a list result, change `sapply` to `lapply` (the `l` stands for `list`). If you want to vary both `n_samps` and `n_cols_to_bin` in parallel, then using `Map` is better, e.g., `Map(function(bin, samp) foo(mat, bin, samp), bin = c(2, 5, 100), samp = c(100, 100, 5))` to get 100, 100, and 5 samples each from 2, 5, and 100 bins, respectively.

Comment: This last solution is perfect for what I need. Thank you so much!