# Aggregate randomly sampled columns for iteratively larger bin sizes

Tags: r, lapply, sample

I have a matrix like so:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,
                2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
                1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,2,1,0,0,0), nrow=16, ncol=6)
dimnames(mat) <- list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m",
                        "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"), 
                      c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

I want to group or bin columns and then aggregate data for each group. Repeat sampling for a bin of size x,  n times. This process would be repeated for bin sizes of x+1.

For the first iteration, two random columns are binned. I would like to sample without replacement such that a combination of two columns is not sampled twice (however a column can be used twice if it is paired with a different column). Aggregation is defined as calculating row sums for the binned columns. Aggregated results will be added as a new column in a result matrix for that bin size. The number of columns in the result matrix will be limited to the number of bins randomly sampled.

Bin size continues to get increasingly larger. For the next iteration, the bin size increases to 3 such that 3 randomly selected columns  are aggregated. Aggregated data will be put into a different result matrix. This process would continue until the bin is the size of the data frame, in which case resampling is impossible. All result matrices would be put into a list of matrices.

Below is the expected result `resultList` for the first two bin sizes given the matrix above.

```
# Bin size =2 
# The randomly sampled columns are columns 1&2, 2&3, 3&4, 4&5, 5&6. 
mat1 <- matrix(c(3,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,
                 2,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                 0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                 0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
                 1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,1), nrow=16)
dimnames(mat1) <- list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", 
                         "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"), 
                       c("1_2", "2_3", "3_4", "4_5", "5_6"))

# Bin size= 3
# The randomly selected columns to be joined are columns 1,2&3, 
# 2,3&4, 3,4&5, 4,5&6. 
mat2 <- matrix(c(3,0,1,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,
                 2,1,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                 0,1,1,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
                 1,2,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,1), nrow=16)
dimnames(mat2) <- list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m",
                         "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"), 
                       c("1_2_3", "2_3_4", "3_4_5", "4_5_6"))
resultList <- list(mat1, mat2)
```

I have posted a similar question for an alternative binning technique here: [Bin columns and aggregate data via random sample with replacement for iteratively larger bin sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083701/bin-columns-and-aggregate-data-via-random-sample-with-replacement-for-iterativel/58084092?noredirect=1#comment102568228_58084092)

Here is my attempt at binning randomly selected columns and putting results for each bin size into a list of matrices. I attempted to select `j` random columns using `sample`, do `rowSums` and remove those selected `j` paired columns so that those are not repeated in the next iteration:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - 1), function(j) 
  do.call(cbind, 
          lapply(sample(ncol(mat) - j, size= ), function(i) 
            rowSums(mat[, i:(i - j)]))))
```

Comment: How does `n` change between iterations? In your example it started at 5 and then it was decreased to 4, is it always a unitary decrease?

Comment: The number of samples taken for each bin size is constrained by bin size. Such that larger bin sizes will have fewer samples that can be randomly drawn hence fewer columns in the result matrix. Therefore, the number of samples will naturally vary for each bin size. Ideally, the maximum number of samples is taken for each bin size (which would result in a unitary decrease) or at least a sample that will produce a sizable sample  (ie. 100 samples).

Comment: How many columns do you expect for each bin size ? If we randomly select columns  without repetition for bin size = 2, there are 6C2 = 15 possible combinations, for bin size = 3 we have 6C3 = 20 combinations where 6 is the number of columns in `mat`. Do you want all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on how many columns you want in your final output, we can modify the approach but currently this gives all possible combination.

```
#Get column names of the matrices
all_cols <- colnames(mat)

#Select bin value from 2:ncol(mat)
total_out <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat))[-1], function(j) {
      #Create all combinations taking j items at a time
      temp <- combn(all_cols, j, function(x) 
              #Take rowSums for the current combination
              #Also paste column names to assign column names later
              list(rowSums(mat[, x]), paste0(x, collapse = "_")), simplify = FALSE)
      #Combine rowSums matrix 
      new_mat <- sapply(temp, `[[`, 1)
      #Assign column names
      colnames(new_mat) <- sapply(temp, `[[`, 2)
      #Return new matrix
      new_mat
})
```

The current output looks like

```
total_out
#[[1]]
#  1_2 1_3 1_4 1_5 1_6 2_3 2_4 2_5 2_6 3_4 3_5 3_6 4_5 4_6 5_6
#a   3   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   0   0   1   0   1   1
#c   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   2   1
#f   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
#h   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
#i   1   1   0   1   0   2   1   2   1   1   2   1   1   0   1
#j   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
#l   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#m   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
#p   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1
#q   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
#s   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   2
#t   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   2   0   0   2   0   2   2
#u   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1
#v   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
#x   3   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
#z   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
#...
#....
#....
#[[5]]
#  1_2_3_4_5_6
#a           4
#c           2
#f           1
#h           1
#i           3
#j           1
#l           1
#m           1
#p           1
#q           1
#s           2
#t           2
#u           1
#v           1
#x           3
#z           1
```

Note that, there are total 5 (`ncol - 1`) matrices in `total_out` with number of columns as

```
length(total_out)
#[1] 5

sapply(total_out, ncol)
#[1] 15 20 15  6  1
```

---

Since, we know that the last element in the list is going to be a one-column matrix we can remove them and select random `nc/2` columns from the remaining matrix.

```
total_out <- total_out[-length(total_out)]

lapply(total_out, function(x) {
     nc <- ncol(x)
     x[, sample(nc, ceiling(nc/2))]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is a start.  Can we modify this by leaving your function as is and  randomly sample from the results? It's variable how many samples can be drawn based on bin size. If C= the number of columns in the result matrix, can we draw C/2 samples from that? This wouldn't work for the last bin size but can for all the rest.

Comment: This works. A minor issue it that the last output is not a matrix, instead it is a named vector due to the lack of combinations at that bin size. Is there a way to update the function so that the last matrix of the largest bin size is removed and not randomly sampled from?

Comment: I know I can add a line that selects my desired elements of a list using `myList<-myList[1:4]` but I am curious if there is a way to remove it using the ifelse loop you created so I can read that output directly into a function I have that preforms a function on a list of matrices (hence the issue with the named vector.

Comment: @Danielle We can remove the last element in the list instead `total_out <- total_out[-length(total_out)]` and then `sample` the remaining ones.

Comment: Or in `lapply`, we can use `total_out <- lapply(2:(ncol(mat) - 1), function(j) {.......` to avoid creating the 1 column matrix in first place.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for all combinations `cx` of `ncol(mat)` of size `x`, where `x` grows from `2` to `ncol(mat) - 1`. You then want samples `cx.s` of this of the size half the number of each `cx`. From `mat` you want the `rowSums()` of the columns denoted by each of the `cx.s` for every `x`.

This solution uses `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral()` which is tremendously faster than `utils::combn()`.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
res <- lapply(2L:(ncol(mat) - 1), function(x) {
  ## matrix 'cx' of all combinations of size 'x'
  cx <- comboGeneral(ncol(mat), x)
  ## sample of 'cx' of size 'ncol(cx)/2' (automatically adjusts downwards)
  cx.s <- cx[sort(sample(nrow(cx), nrow(cx)/2)), ]
  ## apply aggregation on sampled columns of 'mat'
  out <- lapply(1L:nrow(cx.s), function(k) {
    ## sample 'mat.cx.k' of 'mat'
    mat.cx.k <- mat[, cx.s[k, ]]
    ## apply aggregation function and
    ## set attribute 's.cols' with the sampled col numbers
    return(`attr<-`(
      rowSums(mat.cx.k),  ## <-- aggregation function here
      "s.cols", paste(cx.s[k, ], collapse="_")))
  })
  ## cbind to matrix and set colnames from attributes
  return(`colnames<-`(do.call(cbind, out), Map(attr, out, "s.cols")))
})
```

#### UPDATE (*re-updated*)

As we learn from *@Cole*, `RcppAlgos` contains a `comboSample()` function that already handles the sampling of the combinations, so that we are able to code this much more effectively and brief!

*I've learned from your comments to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58083701/6574038), that you're dealing with 600 columns, which would yield a slightly large number with the "sampling-half-of-possible-combinations-approach"...*

```
comboCount(600, 600/2)
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
#   [1] 135107941996194268514474877978504530397233945449193479925965721786474150408005716961950480198274469818673334131365837249043900490761151591695308427048536947621976068789875968372656
```

*...I've therefore implemented kind of a safety-`switch()` with **`max.comb`** into the function.*

```
FUN <- function(mat, max.comb=20) {
  out <- lapply(2L:(ncol(mat) - 1), function(x) {
    ## all combinations of 'ncol(mat)' of size 'x' with half size (adjusts downwards)
    do.call(cbind, {
      n.comb <- comboCount(ncol(mat), x)/2L
      comboSample(ncol(mat), x, n=switch((n.comb > max.comb)+1, floor(n.comb), max.comb),
                  FUN=function(i) 
                    `colnames<-`(as.matrix(
                      rowSums(mat[, i])),  ## <-- aggregation FUN here
                      paste(i, collapse="_")))
      })
  })
  # out <- Map(function(x) x[, order(colnames(x))],  # un-comment for ordered columns
  #            out)                                  # (slower)
  return(out)
} 

set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
res2 <- FUN(mat, max.comb=20)

stopifnot(all.equal(res, res2))  # with ordered columns
```

#### Result

```
res
# [[1]]
#   1_2 1_3 1_5 1_6 2_6 3_4 5_6
# a   3   1   1   2   3   0   1
# c   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
# f   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
# h   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
# i   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
# j   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
# l   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
# m   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
# p   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
# q   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
# s   0   0   1   1   1   0   2
# t   0   0   0   2   2   0   2
# u   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
# v   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
# x   3   2   2   2   1   0   0
# z   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
# 
# [[2]]
#   1_2_4 1_2_6 1_3_4 1_3_6 1_4_6 1_5_6 2_4_5 2_4_6 3_4_5 4_5_6
# a     3     4     1     2     2     2     2     3     0     1
# c     1     1     1     1     2     1     1     2     1     2
# f     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
# h     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
# i     1     1     1     1     0     1     2     1     2     1
# j     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1
# l     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
# m     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
# p     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1
# q     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
# s     0     1     0     1     1     2     1     1     1     2
# t     0     2     0     2     2     2     0     2     0     2
# u     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1
# v     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
# x     3     3     2     2     2     2     1     1     0     0
# z     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
# 
# [[3]]
#   1_2_3_6 1_2_4_5 1_2_4_6 1_3_5_6 2_3_4_5 2_3_5_6 3_4_5_6
# a       4       3       4       2       2       3       1
# c       1       1       2       1       1       1       2
# f       1       0       0       1       1       1       1
# h       1       0       0       1       1       1       1
# i       2       2       1       2       3       3       2
# j       0       1       1       0       1       0       1
# l       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
# m       0       1       0       1       1       1       1
# p       1       0       1       1       0       1       1
# q       0       1       0       1       1       1       1
# s       1       1       1       2       1       2       2
# t       2       0       2       2       0       2       2
# u       1       0       1       1       0       1       1
# v       0       1       0       1       1       1       1
# x       3       3       3       2       1       1       0
# z       0       1       0       1       1       1       1
# 
# [[4]]
#   1_2_4_5_6 1_3_4_5_6 2_3_4_5_6
# a         4         2         3
# c         2         2         2
# f         0         1         1
# h         0         1         1
# i         2         2         3
# j         1         1         1
# l         1         1         0
# m         1         1         1
# p         1         1         1
# q         1         1         1
# s         2         2         2
# t         2         2         2
# u         1         1         1
# v         1         1         1
# x         3         2         1
# z         1         1         1
```

Tested on a 16x600 matrix gives quite usable timing results:

```
system.time(FUN(mat[, sample(ncol(mat), 600, replace=TRUE)], max.comb=20))
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.91    0.00    2.95
```

*@Combs* `array` approach might give a few extra % performance more.

If necessary, you can also add the row sums of the un-sampled `mat` with `append()`.

```
res <- append(res, 
              list(`colnames<-`(as.matrix(rowSums(mat)), paste(1:ncol(mat), collapse="_"))))
```

#### Data

```
mat <- structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(16L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", 
"p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v", "x", "z"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6")))
```

Comment: you may want to use ```RcppAlgos::comboSample```.  It would largely account for your ```cx``` and ```cx.s``` statements in one go and be more performant - why create combos if they don't need to be used.

Comment: @Cole How great is that, I didn't know the function before, see update!

Comment: I compared your function vs. the array function. The array method was 2.9 s vs. 3.1 s for yours. My array method probably isn't worth it - I mean I go from ```rowSums``` to ```colSums``` so the readability isn't the best. +1 for looking at OP's other post. Your modification with ```max.col``` will work out of the box.

Comment: @Cole My reading is 2.96 vs 2.84 for yours, though. I used `microbenchmark` with `times=10L` and the 16x600 matrix, both FUNs with the `switch()` ;)

Answer (score 1):

This function includes options to pick a percent of the combinations in `prob` or directly the maximum number of `cols` for each column sampling.

```
f_combos <- function(k, prob = 1L, cols = NULL) {
## k is the number of columns used in each combination

## prob is 0L < prob < 1L which is the percentage of each
## combination that will be included in the final output

## cols is the number of columns of each combination that
## will be included in the final output.

## If cols is passed, it is prioritized over any prob.


#Returns original matrix if you send k = 1 (i.e., one column) or
# will send rowSums of original matrix if k == ncols. 
  if (k == 1){
    return(mat) 
  } else if (k == ncol(mat)) { 
    return(matrix(rowSums(mat),
                  dimnames = list(rownames(mat),
                                  paste(colnames(mat),
                                        collapse = '_'))
    )
    )
  } 

 #create all unique combinations based on k columns selected
  all_combos <- combn(ncol(mat), k)


 #determines how many combos will be used
  if  (!is.null(cols)){
    n <- ifelse(cols < ncol(all_combos), cols, ncol(all_combos))
    } else if (prob < 1L) {
      n <- ceiling(prob * ncol(all_combos))
      } else {
        n <- ncol(all_combos)
        }

 #resamples the combos if necessary 
  if (n < ncol(all_combos)){
    all_combos <- all_combos[, sample(ncol(all_combos), n)]
    if ( n == 1) {
      return(matrix(rowSums(mat[, all_combos]),
                    dimnames = list(rownames(mat),
                                    paste(all_combos,
                                          collapse = '_'))
      )
      )
    } 
  }

 #this subsets the matrix all at once. 
 ##Then, array() creates a M x k x N array.  
 ## The array is then transposed with aperm() to more efficiently calculate everything
 ###with colSums
  colSums(
    aperm(
      array(
        mat[, as.vector(all_combos)],
        dim = c(nrow(mat), k, ncol(all_combos)),
        dimnames = list(rownames(mat), NULL, apply(all_combos, 2, paste0, collapse = '_'))
      ),
      perm = c(2,1,3)
    )
  )
}
```

This function largely simplifies down to this (using `RcppAlgos`):

```
library(RcppAlgos)
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)-1)[-1],
       function(k) {
         n_combos <- ceiling(comboCount(ncol(mat), k) / 2)

         all_combos <- comboSample(ncol(mat), k, n = n_combos)

         colSums(
           aperm(
             array(
               mat[, as.vector(t(all_combos))],
               dim = c(nrow(mat), k, nrow(all_combos)),
               dimnames = list(rownames(mat), NULL, apply(all_combos, 1, paste0, collapse = '_'))
             ),
             perm = c(2,1,3)
           )
         )
       }
)
```

The function will work with:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), f_combos)
```

If you include `f_combos(k = 1)`, the first list output will be the original matrix. All other returns will be based on the optional arguments `prob` and `cols`.

In action: get only 1 column:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)-1)[-1], f_combos, , 1)
#all truncated to the first 3 rows
[[1]]
  2_5
a   2
c   0
f   0

[[2]]
  1_2_4
a     3
c     1
f     0

[[3]]
  1_2_3_4
a       3
c       1
f       1

[[4]]
  1_2_3_4_5
a         3
c         1
f         1
```

Half of the columns:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), f_combos, 0.5)
#all truncated to the first 3 rows
[[1]]
  1_5 1_2 1_3 3_5 3_4 5_6 2_3 2_6
a   1   3   1   0   0   1   2   3
c   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
f   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0

[[2]]
  1_4_5 2_3_5 1_5_6 3_5_6 1_2_4 2_3_4 2_5_6 2_4_5 1_3_6 1_4_6
a     1     2     2     1     3     2     3     2     2     2
c     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2
f     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0

[[3]]
  1_4_5_6 1_2_4_5 2_3_5_6 1_2_5_6 1_2_4_6 1_2_3_4 2_4_5_6 1_2_3_6
a       2       3       3       4       4       3       3       4
c       2       1       1       1       2       1       2       1
f       0       0       1       0       0       1       0       1

[[4]]
  2_3_4_5_6 1_2_3_5_6 1_2_4_5_6
a         3         4         4
c         2         1         2
f         1         1         0
```